# MongoDb - copy one database to another keeping the users also

Tags: mongodb

I want to copy from one mongo db to another db on the same server. Mongo version is 2.6.3 on Win 2008 64bit.

I ran the command:

mongo localhost:27017/admin -u <> -p <> --eval "db.copyDatabase('db_master','db_copy1')"

This worked and created db_copy1 with all the users in it. I did db.getUsers() on db_copy1 and it returned all users. All was fine.

Then I went on to copy the database db_copy1 to db_copy2 using the same command above (with different database names obviously). But the resultant db_copy2 had no users in it.

Fairly new to mongo, so quite possible I have missed something.

Thanks in advance for all your help!
Vikram

Answer (score 0):

One of the things I love about Mongodb is that rather than mess about with commands like that you can just copy the files.

Just go to the directory with the data files in it and copy them to the dbpath for your new database. If you don't want a certain database, don't copy the files with that database name!

Comment: Thanks. very helpful to know this. I get the same behaviour when I  copy the files. db_master returns one user when I run db.getUsers(). Then copy the db_master.* files and rename them as db_master_copy and I could see this new database in show dbs. But o this new database, if I do db.getUsers(), it comes back with empty value. Not sure whats going on. Is user information stored somewhere else?

Comment: I was certain it was stored in the same place! Oh well.